# VBA Excel How to insert new column before cell.value = "" for Each cel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table with 40 cells that contains value "total" now I have to insert new column before every cell that contains Total. Please help I'm desperate. This is what I came with so far.. I don't know how to order it to do it throughout all "2:2", meaning after you find first Total go on do that until empty cell. I've tried with `Do Until IsEmpty(Active.Cell)` but it does nothing for me. HELPP :(

```
Dim INC As Range
Set INC = Range("2:2").Find("Total")
If INC Is Nothing Then
  MsgBox "Total column was not found."
  Exit Sub
Else
  Columns(INC.Column).Offset(, 0).Resize(, 1).Insert
End If
```

Comment: you need to insert an entire column for every "total", or move (shift) the contents (of this row only) 1 cell to the right?

Comment: I just need to insert new empty column before every total. First 2 solutions that I have just insert new column for first total, they doesn't proceed to another total cell. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edited after OP's showing data structure

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()
    Dim f As Range
    Dim firstAddress As String

    With Worksheets("Totals")
        With .Rows(2).SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues)
            Set f = .Find(what:="Total", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
            If Not f Is Nothing Then
                firstAddress = f.Offset(, 1).Address '<-- offset by one column since f will be shifted one column to the right in subsequent statement
                Do
                    f.EntireColumn.Insert
                    Set f = .FindNext(f)
                Loop While f.Address <> firstAddress
            End If
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: the PO wanted to stop in the first empty cell, your solution (which is clean and nice) will keep running even if encountered an empty cell in the middle

Comment: @ShaiRado. You may be right. But from OP words _"after you find first Total go on do that until empty cell."_, I assumed that "total" could be spread in many cells along Row 2 that could also be separated by blank ones. So I had that loop go until the last not empty cell in row 2. Anyhow should not be like that (we'll know that as soon as Sofija will give some feedback) the code change would be easy to spot

Comment: This code just insert alot of new columns before first total. I've try to modify it with

Then
Columns(INC2.Column).Offset(, 0).Resize(, 1).Insert

But it did the same. :(

@user3598756  You are right there is about 40 totals in row 2. I need to loop through out all of them and insert new column before everyone cell that has Total. :( Can you help me :(

Comment: Yes, it just insert alot of new columns before first total. :( And it doesnt look for another Tota. :(

Comment: add a link to an image of your worksheet so as to see what's in the row with Totals

Answer (score 0):

this will insert a column to the left of the cells in row 2 with total as value, note the extra i = i + 1 as you need to skip an extra column because you've just added one :)

```
Public Sub test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim i As Integer
    i = 1

    Do While (ws.Cells(2, i).Value <> "")

        If (ws.Cells(2, i).Value = "total") Then

            ws.Cells(2, i).EntireColumn.Insert
            i = i + 1

        End If

        i = i + 1

    Loop


End Sub
```

Comment: This code doesn't work :( I've try to modify it, but it won't work. :(